# Exception thrown in referenced project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, exception, reference

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution consisting of 2 projects:

1. **Core**, a C# class library project which handles the functionality and data access
2. **UI**, an ASP.NET 4 website (.NET Framework 4) that references the Core, and calls functionality in the Core.

My exception handler is set in Global.asax (Application_Error.)
When an exception occurs in the UI, everything works perfectly, I get filename, line number, etc.

This is not the case for exceptions that occur in the Core.
For this, I get a stacktrace like:

```
{FillUserCount at offset 2376 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0}
```

P.S. The Core.dll and Core.pdb are present in the UI Bin folder.
In Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> "Enable just my code" is unchecked and "Enable source server support" is checked.

**Is there a way to get stackframe info (filename, class, method, line number) also for errors that occured in my referenced project ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to get this working was to create a new web site and re-referencing the Core project.

Still, the prerequisites that Jon Skeet mentioned remain the same:

- the projects have to be built in Debug configuration, and not Release
- while referencing a project, make sure PDB files are copied
- on code side, when retrieving info about the exception that occured, and using StackTrace, make sure you create the instance with the second parameter set to true (true to capture the file name, line number, and column number; otherwise, false.)

This is my final working code. It may help others:

```
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();       

        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
        if (trace.FrameCount == 0)
            return;

        StackFrame stackFrame = trace.GetFrame(0);

        string className, fileName, functionName, message;
        int line = 0;

        // if for some reason, filename is being retrieved as null
        if (stackFrame.GetFileName() == null)
        {
            className = ex.TargetSite.ReflectedType.Name;
            fileName = ex.TargetSite.ReflectedType.Name;
            functionName = ex.TargetSite.Name;
            message = ex.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            // Collect data where exception occured
            string[] splitFile = stackFrame.GetFileName().Split('\\');
            className = splitFile[splitFile.Length - 1];
            fileName = stackFrame.GetFileName();
            functionName = stackFrame.GetMethod().Name;
            message = ex.Message;
            line = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you referencing Core? If you've added a reference to the "Release" DLL, that would explain it... if you've just added a reference to the *project* and you're running a build with the "Debug" configuration then it should be okay.

Comment: Core is referenced via Project Reference. Both Core and UI run in Debug mode.
After viewing your question, I tried creating the exact same structure, one solution, with 2 projects and for the newly created one, everything is ok. I compared both solutions side by side for any project build configs, but everything is exactly the same.

How can one solution (the basic created one) work as intended, and the other one still not showing Filename, Method, Line, etc ? 
There must be something that I'm missing.

Comment: @Daniel: Hmm... odd. When you say "run in Debug mode" - do you mean you're building the debug configuration? That's the important bit.

Comment: Yes, I am building both the Core and UI in debug configuration. Is this wrong ?

Comment: @Daniel: Nope, that's absolutely right. It should be fine. Check that the PDB file is being copied across and looks like it's got the right size.

Comment: PDB is indeed being copied correctly into the Bin folder of the UI and has the exact same size as the one in Core/Bin. Also, the stack is initialized with the true parameter to have access to filename, etc (StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(ex, true)), except it doesn't work.

Comment: @Daniel: When you say "Core/Bin" do you mean "Core/Bin/Debug"? I'm not sure why you're creating your own stack trace though - the exception should have it itself in Exception.StackTrace.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Core/Bin/Debug. The stack trace object that I'm creating has as parameter the exception that just occured, caught via Server.GetLastError(), in Global.asax. I'm doing so to have access to properties like filename, line number by using StackFrame stackFrame = trace.GetFrame(0);

Comment: @Daniel: So if you fetch the stack trace as a string by calling Exception.StackTrace, does *that* have the relevant information?

Comment: Sure it does, with one drawback, the relevant data is somewhere in that string, serialized. I personally like using StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(ex, true) for giving me the option to iterate through the frames of the StackTrace and displaying the amount of data I need. If there's a more flexible way of handling this, I'd be glad to know. Thanks a lot for the help, Jon ! :)

Comment: @Daniel: This was mostly for diagnostic purposes. The fact that the data is there means that it must be in the PDB file you've got deployed - so that means you don't need to go checking any more settings etc. The information's there, it's "just" a matter of extracting it.